# Threejs soft shadows for point light

Tags: three.js, shadows

Is there a way to have soft shadows with PointLight in Threejs?

Like in the picture below:

[image: soft shadows]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. To have soft shadows in your scene you have to set the renderer like this:

```
 var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
 renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
 renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap; // the default is THREE.PCFShadowMap
```

Source:  [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/lights/shadows/LightShadow)

Comment: Increase the shadow map `light.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048; light.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;` to get a higher shadow resolution.

Comment: This itself does NOT provide an answer to the question. This will create a shadow but nowhere soft like on OP's image.